# I have translation API, how can I localize my flutter app using API

Tags: android, flutter

// this is my api resposne.

{
"statusCode": 200,
"status": "success",
"message": "translate data",
"result": [
{
"hello": "hello"
}
]
}

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use an API to localize your app's offline content because sometimes the user has to wait too much for your API to respond (also there's a possibility that it'd never respond).
The best way to do it is to make a dictionary because you already have offline texts and it's easy to translate them. then you can change texts completely offline.

**Edit:**

If you have no other option, here's the code that may help you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui show TextHeightBehavior;

class LocalizedText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? data;

  final TextStyle? style;

  final StrutStyle? strutStyle;

  final TextAlign? textAlign;

  final TextDirection? textDirection;

  final Locale? locale;

  final bool? softWrap;

  final TextOverflow? overflow;

  final double? textScaleFactor;

  final int? maxLines;

  final String? semanticsLabel;

  final TextWidthBasis? textWidthBasis;

  final ui.TextHeightBehavior? textHeightBehavior;

  const LocalizedText(this.data,
      {Key? key,
      this.style,
      this.strutStyle,
      this.textAlign,
      this.textDirection,
      this.locale,
      this.softWrap,
      this.overflow,
      this.textScaleFactor,
      this.maxLines,
      this.semanticsLabel,
      this.textWidthBasis,
      this.textHeightBehavior})
      : assert(
          data != null,
          'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
        ),
        super(key: key);
  @override
  _LocalizedTextState createState() => _LocalizedTextState();
}

class _LocalizedTextState extends State<LocalizedText> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  String? _translatedText;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callApi();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      _isLoading
          ? "Loding..." //Your Loading Text here, You can also use 'widget.data!' to show original text while waiting for Api result
          : _translatedText ??
              widget
                  .data!, //if the Api doesn't respond or fail, the original text will apear
      key: widget.key,
      locale: widget.locale,
      maxLines: widget.maxLines,
      overflow: widget.overflow,
      semanticsLabel: widget.semanticsLabel,
      softWrap: widget.softWrap,
      strutStyle: widget.strutStyle,
      style: widget.style,
      textAlign: widget.textAlign,
      textDirection: widget.textDirection,
      textHeightBehavior: widget.textHeightBehavior,
      textScaleFactor: widget.textScaleFactor,
      textWidthBasis: widget.textWidthBasis,
    );
  }

  void callApi() async {
    var response;
    //Call your API here
    _isLoading = false;
    if (response["statusCode"] == 200) {
      _translatedText = response["result"]...;  //You should set your translated text from Api to _translatedText
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Use it like this: `LocalizedText("Hello")`

If You want to optimize it more you can save the translated words locally and check them before calling the Api.

Comment: It's  a production based application so I have to use API for translation.

Comment: I edited the answer, check it.